# Nlog Concat to write to specific log

Tags: c#, concatenation, nlog

I have a method which I need to do a concat of some sort. Basically ClassNameLogger is the nlog object and can write to .debug or .warn (so ClassNameLogger.debug). I want to make the method unviersal so the user can define the level it writes to by passing it through as a parameter.

```
 public void LogWarning(Exception ex, LogLevel level)
    {
        ClassNameLogger.  ("")
    }
```

The LogLevel level is an enum of the different log types (Debug, Warn, Fatal) and I need it to essentially write ClassNameLogger.Debug assuming that the level parameter is "debug" or ClassNameLogger.Warn if the level parameter was "Warn"

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about `ClassNameLogger.Log(level, ex)`?

Comment: ofcourse! Why didn't I think of that!!!!

Comment: There is already a `Logger.Log(....)` in NLog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Crozin - as he confirmed nlog has an option to do this with .log(level, ex)